# Does my wife needs to take an IELTS test if I apply for an immigration PNP program to Canada?

Tags: canada, ielts

I want to move to Canada from a non-English speaking country with my wife.

Does my wife have to take an IELTS test if I were to apply for a PNP program to Canada?

Comment: Assuming you mean the Provincial Nominee Programs, as the name suggests, they are not a uniform program. They are offered by each participating provinces and territories individually and the requirements differ for different provinces and different subprograms within that province.

Comment: Thanks very much. My target is PEI Business Impact project.

Answer (score 1):

For the PEI Business Impact program, the spouse can provide a language result at CLB/NCLC 6 level or higher for 10 points in the adaptability category when assessing your expression of interest. However, this is not required if you don't want the points.

See page 11 of https://www.princeedwardisland.ca/sites/default/files/publications/business_guide_1.pdf

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and the material.